# Block Scoping Issue in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, scope, ecmascript-6

I am having some issues with block scoping in Node.   I am attempting to build a object stuffed with some stats from the database.   The issue I am running into is the object gets defined just fine inside of a mongoose db call, but is undefined outside of it.

I have also tried doing it as an array and doing stats.push(), and both ways with a setTimeout (set to 300ms).   Any suggestions?   I could do a method on the model I supposed, but I would rather learn about what i'm doing wrong here.

```
    app.get('/api/v1/authenticated/admin/stats/get', function(req, res) {
      let stats = {};
      User.find().count(function(err, count){
          stats.userCount = count;
      console.log('usrCnt inside of db ' + stats.userCount);  //defined.  Shows in the console after the console.log below.
      });
      console.log('UsrCount outside of db ' + stats.userCount);  //undefined
      res.send(stats);
    });
```

Comment: Sooo...send the response in the callback to `count()` where you have the value.

Comment: Nothing to do with block scoping...everything to do with async. :)

Comment: @slugonamission, I could send the response, but what if I want to add additional counts from other models to the object and send the response all at once?

Comment: Then use one of the functions from the `async` library, or only send the response when you have collected all of the results you need. The duplicate answer should have a few ways of doing this.